# Odd tr/// operator behavior with the /c modifier in Perl

Tags: perl, tr

The `/c` modifier does something I don't understand here. I want to know why the following code will print "abc3333"?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$x = 'abcdefg';
$x =~ tr/abc/123/c;
print $x;
```

Comment: This is a valid question, though perhaps poorly phrased. The `/c` modifier on the transliteration stands for "complement", which is explained in perlop `"If the /c modifier is specified, the SEARCHLIST character set is complemented."`, which is a very weak explanation indeed. Basically, it means it transliterates any characters which does not match "abc".

Comment: And who removed "tr" from the title of this question? How is `How to use in perl?` a valid question anywhere?

Comment: Perhaps you'd stand more chance of understanding it if you read the documentation - http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/c` causes the searchlist to be complemented; that is, every character *not* listed is searched for.

Assuming you have only characters in the range `\0-\xff`, this:

```
tr/abc/123/c
```

is equivalent to this:

```
tr/\0-\x60\x64-\xff/123/
```

and the last character of the replacement list is repeated as many times as necessary to match the number of characters in the search list (when not using /d).

So a "\0" becomes "1", "\1" becomes "2", "a", "b", or "c" are unchanged, and any other character becomes "3".

It is fairly unusual to specify a replacement list with /c; usually /c is used just for counting:

```
tr/abc//c # returns number of non-abc characters; string is unchanged
```

or deleting:

```
tr/0-9//cd # delete all non-digits
```

Comment: To ysth:You write wrong in `tr/abc//c`,the right is `tr/abc/ /c`

Comment: @baozailove: no, with a space it will change all nul characters to spaces.  only with an empty replacementlist (and no /d) does tr/// become just a counting operator.  Why do you think there should be a space?

Comment: To ysth:You said `tr/abc//c #returns number of non-abc characters;`,but i execute the code that return `abcdefg` and don't return `no abc characters`

Comment: @baozailove: `$x = "ajdsfjwlljja"; print $x =~ tr/abc//c;` prints 10 (and leaves `$x` unchanged).  I'm not sure what you are saying, can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

`/c` is usually used to modify `/d`

```
tr/...//d;    # Delete every matching char.
tr/...//cd;   # Delete every char that doesn't match.
```

or for counting.

```
tr/...//;    # Returns number of matching chars.
tr/...//c;   # Returns number of chars that don't match.
```

I can't come up with a useful example for it with a non-empty replacement set, but it's simple to explain: It simply uses the complements the search set. Keeping in mind that `a`, `b` and `c` are characters 0x61, 0x62 and 0x63,

```
tr/abc/123/c;
```

is therefore equivalent to

```
tr/\x00-\x60\x64-\x{FFFFFFFFF}/123/;            # Perl with 32bit ints
  or
tr/\x00-\x60\x64-\x{FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF}/123/;   # Perl with 64bit ints
```

Keeping in mind that the last char of the replacement set is used for chars with no corresponding char in the search set,

- `"\x00"` becomes `1`
- `"\x01"` becomes `2`
- Everything else that matches becomes `3`.

This behaviour is entirely consistent with the `tr` command line tool on which `tr///` is based. I'm not sure how `/c` could ever be useful without `/d`, but maybe it is for the extra features the `tr` command line tool has over `tr///` (such as character classes).

Comment: I found this a little confusing so added my own answer :)

Comment: @ikegami:why `a` are characters 0x61?

Comment: @baozailove: because that is the character code for 'a' in ASCII and utf8: `printf "%x\n", ord("a");`

Comment: @baozailove, Each code point has a number. That's the number for `a`. `"a"` and `"\x61"` produce the same string.

Answer (score 0):

The `/c` modifier affects the *complement* of the characters in the list. It's mainly of use together with the `/d` modifier, to delete all but a given set of characters.

```
my $string = 'ABCdef123';
$string =~ tr/a-z//cd;
print $string;
```

**output**

```
def
```